# Retrieving dynamic sets of columns from a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Assigning sets of columns whose names are stored in a character vector is well discussed, but I can't seem to find a solution to retrieve columns and operate on them.

```
cols = c("x", "y")
DT = data.table(x = 10:15, y = 20:25)

> DT
    x  y
1: 10 20
2: 11 21
3: 12 22
4: 13 23
5: 14 24
6: 15 25
```

**Desired Output**

```
> DT[,paste(x,y)]

[1] "10 20" "11 21" "12 22" "13 23" "14 24" "15 25"
```

My goal is to get a unique identifier for each row based on the columns in `cols`. I can do this by hard coding the column names but I'd rather reference `cols`

---

Here are some syntax I have tried and their output.

**get()**

```
> DT[,get(cols)]

[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

**Parentheses**

```
> DT[,(cols)]

[1] "x" "y"
```

**List**

```
> DT[,as.list(cols)]
   V1 V2
1:  x  y
```

**with=F**

```
> DT[,cols, with=F]

    x  y
1: 10 20
2: 11 21
3: 12 22
4: 13 23
5: 14 24
6: 15 25
```

This works but I am unable to operate on the columns:

```
> DT[,paste(cols), with=F]

    x  y
1: 10 20
2: 11 21
3: 12 22
4: 13 23
5: 14 24
6: 15 25
```

Comment: Fyi, `paste(cols)` is the same as `cols`, and in the latest version of data.table, `with=FALSE` isn't necessary in some of these cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `paste` with `do.call` on the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
DT[, do.call(paste, .SD)]
#[1] "10 20" "11 21" "12 22" "13 23" "14 24" "15 25"
```

If this needs to be done on a subset of columns, specify those columns in `.SDcols` and then do the above

```
DT[, do.call(paste, .SD), .SDcols = cols]
#[1] "10 20" "11 21" "12 22" "13 23" "14 24" "15 25"
```

Or use a modification of OP's solution with `mget`

```
DT[, do.call(paste, mget(cols))]
```

Comment: This was a very illustrative answer. Thanks.